# ASP.NET MVC Confusion when converting Model Object before DB insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm confused about "the journey" of the data and I need some confirmation. Could you check this underneath and correct me if necessary. It's also not clear to me in case of an insert.

On one hand, I have a "simple DAL" with POCO Objects, a Mapper converting IDataRecord into POCO Objects and Services in charge of Connexion and Command to communicate with the DB.

On the other hand, I have an MVC project with Model Objects, Controllers in charge of asking the DAL Services to work for them, and a Mapper which converts Model Objects to POCO Objects and also the POCO Objects into Model Objects.

And finally, the views...

In case of retrieving the Data from the DB, I understand the journey of those data like this :

- the View sends an httprequest to the Controller
- the Controller uses the DAL Services to connect to the DB and execute a query
- the DB sends back some IDataRecord
- the DAL Mapper converts those IDataRecord into POCO Objects
- the MVC Mapper converts those POCO Objects into Model Objects
- the Controller sends those Model Objects back to the View
- the View displays them on the page

In case of inserting the Data to the DB, I understand the journey like this :

- the View send Model Objects to the Controller
- the MVC Mapper converts those Model Objects into POCO Objects
- the Controller asks the DAL Services to connect to the DB and insert the data thanks to a query
- the DB gets the data and stores them

In case of an insert, the DAL Services can send straightaway the POCO Objects to the DB whereas in case of retrieving the Data from the DB, we first need a mapper to convert the IDataRecord into POCO Objects.

Is that right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 3 tier, yea. DAL gives poco. DAL takes Poco. Or you can just send data as parameters.

Comment: So when DAL gives poco with AddParameter to specify what C# field correspond to DB column record, there is no casting needed? We re just sending objects fields to the DB and that's all.. 
I was naively expecting an ultimate cast before sending the data to the DB...like we have it in the case of retrieving data from the DB to the poco

Answer (score 0):

That is - as far as I can tell - correct in a DB first approach. However in a code first approach there is no POCO object and the developer writes those classes.

Comment: not sure I get what you says.. I learned to write poco classes to be used as intermediate objects between the DB and the Model classes